I can not use JQUERY Steps in dynamic forms
I want to use my script and want if use some methods ,I had to return to custom step in my steps form for control of my step form, I have 4 steps, and in step 3 I want use of my C# method

(function ($) {
    "use strict"

    var form = $("#step-form-horizontal");
    form.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true,
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            // Check if the user is moving to the second step
            if (newIndex === 1) {
                // Scroll to the top of the page
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
            }
            // Validate the form on each step change
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        }
    });

    var form2 = $("#step-form-tab");
    form2.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableFinishButton: false,
        enablePagination: false,
        enableAllSteps: true,
        titleTemplate: "#title#"
    });

    var form3 = $('#step-form-vertical');
    form3.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        stepsOrientation: "vertical"
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#deliveryPaymentForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

            // Serialize form data
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            // Send AJAX request to save data
            $.ajax({
                url: '/UserPanel/Home/SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log('Successfully saved delivery and payment details.');
                        ShowMessage('Delivery and payment details saved successfully.');
                         $('#step-form-vertical').steps('setStep', 2);
                        // Move to step 3 in the vertical form
                        window.location.href = '/UserPanel/CheckOut';
                       
                    } else {
                        ShowMessage('Error saving details: ' + response.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error saving details.');
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);

But I see this error and I can not do future level: I want do  first method , then goes to Checkout method and return to step2 in step form
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at F (jquery.min.js:2:36225)
    at B.get (jquery.min.js:2:36831)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:84556)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:85338)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3777)
    at e.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1903)
    at e.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:85310)
    at e.fn.<computed> [as submit] (jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js:154:131)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery-steps-init.js:48:21)

